# The upload path does not appear to be valid

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use the exact code from the CI

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

but it always keep on giving me same error that

The upload path does not appear to be valid.

The folder is there and path is ok . Folder has write permission .

Controller code is this

```
<?php

  class Upload extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

}

function index()
{
    $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
}

function do_upload()
{

    $config['upload_path'] = '/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';
    print_r($config);

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        //echo 'path : '.$config['upload_path'];

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
    //echo "submited";
}
 }?>
```

Comment: check link again $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';

Comment: sorry that was a typo error . It is as u mentioned  $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/'; but giving same error

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out the problem . I was creating the folder in the controller folder . The upload folder should be created at the root folder where Codeignator is installed . 
In my case CI was installed at this path

localhost/CI/

so i created the folder with name of upload and it works for me .

Answer (score 0):

Just create a folder with name `'uploads'` in application folder directory. And change you upload path coding line in your controller like below.

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
```

Comment: thanks for the reply . Earlier i was creating folder in controller folder i created the folder in application directory but still its giving me same error .

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on following line.

```
 $this->load->library('upload', $config);
 $this->upload->initialize($config);
```

Instead of this just do

```
 $this->upload->initialize($config);
```

and load upload library from auto load.